# Can a rscript be aware of other Rscripts in ubuntu

Tags: r, cron

I have a cron job that launches an Rscript to go fetch some data and stash it away in a database.  Sometimes the source isn't ready so it waits.  Sometimes the source skips a data point so the script ends up waiting until another instance is started from cron.  Now that two instances are running they cause problems with each other.  Is there something like the following pseudo code that I could put at the top of my scripts so they stop when they see another instance of themselves is already running:

`stopifnot(Sys.running('nameofscript.r'))`

One thing I thought to do would be for the script to make a temp file with a fixed name at the start and then delete that temp file at the end.  This way the script can check for the existence of the file to know if it's already running.  I also see there's something called `flock` which is probably a better solution than that but I'd prefer if there was a way R can do it without bash commands (I've never really learned any bash).  If there isn't a pure R way to do this, can the R script call flock on itself or would it only work if the cron task calls a bash script that then calls the rscript.  If it isn't already obvious, I don't really know how to use flock.

Comment: I'm using `flock`: `flock -w 1 /tmp/Rscript.lockfile Rscript exec_script.R`. It prevents to run cron task for second time. It is not perfect, it failed to remove lock once in a year for me. You can simply use database to control that.

Comment: I use lockrun
http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.html